# Getting value from a JSON string with space in key

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json string as below. I want to get value within it by referring to a particular key. I tried accessing it directly and also tried using a loop. Both failed:

```
{"CGST - FU": 9.0, "SGST - FU": 9.0}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var data = '{"CGST - FU": 9.0, "SGST - FU": 9.0}'

//Get value of key 
console.log(data['CGST - FU']);
    
 for (var key of Object.keys(data)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + data[key])
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in string format. So your keys are index & value is character at that index.
You'll need to parse it to JSON first. Check below implementation:

```js
var dataString = '{"CGST - FU": 9.0, "SGST - FU": 9.0}'
var data = JSON.parse(dataString)//json format
//Get value of key 
console.log(data['CGST - FU']);
    
 for (var key of Object.keys(data)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + data[key])
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use JSON.parse for change string of object to object

```js
var data = '{"CGST - FU": 9.0, "SGST - FU": 9.0}'

console.log(JSON.parse(data)['CGST - FU']);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works,

```
var data = '{"CGST - FU": 9.0, "SGST - FU": 9.0}'

const value = data.match("CGST - FU")
value[0] // CGST - FU
```